# PYODBC--Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

```
import pyodbc
connection = pyodbc.connect('Driver = {SQL Server};Server=SIWSQL43A\SIMSSPROD43A;'
                            'Database=CSM_reporting;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
```

Error:

```
connection = pyodbc.connect('Driver = {SQL Server};Server=SIWSQL43A\SIMSSPROD43A;'
    pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Answer (score 55):

Do not put a space after the `Driver` keyword in the connection string.

This fails on Windows ...

```python
conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER = {SQL Server};'
    r'SERVER=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;'
    r'DATABASE=myDb;'
    r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
```

... but this works:

```python
conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={SQL Server};'
    r'SERVER=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;'
    r'DATABASE=myDb;'
    r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
```

Comment: "Do not put a space after the Driver keyword in the connection string." This one works for me.. I was confused initially that what was wrong.. :-) +1 for this..

Comment: I still get this error message on Windows without the space.

Comment: @AdrianKeister - That error message can have many different causes. Please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with a [mcve].

Comment: @GordThompson I figured out my error: on Windows you need to use the `{SQL SERVER}` driver. So now I check the `os.platform` string and use the right connection string accordingly.

Comment: @AdrianKeister - Good to hear that you got it working. However, be aware that the `{SQL Server}` driver that ships with Windows is pretty ancient (circa SQL Server 2000) and may prove limiting when working with current versions of SQL Server. Microsoft now maintains modern ODBC Drivers for Windows, Mac, and (at least some flavours of) Linux. `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server` is currently the newest.

Comment: @GordThompson Ah, I see. I went ahead and install driver 17 and reverted my code. I'll see how that works.

Comment: So for some of us, we need to specify the right driver?

Answer (score 55):

I am also getting same error. Finally I have found the solution.

We can search odbc in our local program and check for version of odbc. In my case I have version 17 and 11 so. I have used 17 in connection string

[image]

> 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'

Comment: This is the correct answer in my opinion but some more details could be added.

The Driver version specified needs to match the driver installed on the local machine that is running the code.

The driver has to be compatible with the target server version but this is mostly a non issue because the drivers have pretty brought compatibility, especially if you use the current driver version (right now version 17)

Comment: This approach has worked for me.
Thanks @Sanjiv

Comment: Ahh, yeah, this may be what people are looking for more often.

Comment: it's working, check your SQL version and enter, my side SQL version 13 
like this : `{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}`

Comment: If you do not have the ODBC driver, you need to [Download ODBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16).

Answer (score 22):

I've met same problem and fixed it changing connection string like below.
Write

```
'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}'
```

instead of

```
'DRIVER={SQL Server}'
```

Comment: I have it the way you have it written here and I still get that same error that the question asker had

Comment: For some reason, the opposite worked for me. So I'd recommend trying out both.

Comment: @bernando_vialli can you please see my answer below, I just put all options which can be in place,

Comment: @NeelotpalShukla I have two machines I am using, a personal laptop and a work laptop. For some reason, each works differently. I am not sure why tbh

Answer (score 21):

I'm using Django 2.2

and got the same error while connecting to **sql-server 2012**. Spent lot of time to solve this issue and finally this worked.

I changed driver to

> 'driver': 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0'

and it worked.

Comment: Yes, this is weird, i did the same as "@Avnish alok" and it worked. Guess we just need to try different Driver={xxx} until it works. I was connecting to the below SQL Server "Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4505224) - 14.0.2027.2 (X64)   Jun 15 2019 00:26:19   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Web Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor) "

Comment: I've got SQL Server 2019 installed and Avnish's fix worked for me, too.

Answer (score 10):

Local Ms Sql database server need or {ODBC driver 17 for SQL Server}
Azure Sql Database need{ODBC driver 13 for SQL SERVER}

Check installed drivers here => [Installed ODBC Drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Me5i8.png)

Format for connection to Azure Sql Database is :

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};'
                      'SERVER=tcp:nameServer.database.windows.net,1433;'
                      'DATABASE=Name database; UID=name; PWD=password;')
```

Format for connection to Ms SQL Databse Local is:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                      'SERVER=server.name;' // example Doctor-Notebook\\MSSQLEXPRESS
                      'DATABASE=database.name; Trusted_connection = yes')
```

Answer (score 5):

I faced this issue and was looking for the solution. Finally I was trying all the options from the https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-Windows , and for my MSSQL 12 only "{ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server}" works. Just try it one by one. And the second important thing you have to get correct server name, because I thought preciously that I need to set \SQLEXPRESS in all of the cases, but found out that you have to set EXACTLY what you see in the server properties. Example on the screenshot: [image]

Comment: this lead me to my answer, because I had '{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}' from a tutorial and mine only worked with  '{SQL Server}'.

Comment: This is wrong. You need to specify the driver that is installed on the machine running the python code. For example, Driver 17 worked for me when connecting to a SQL 2014 server, when my code ran on my dev PC, but when I moved it to the same server that was running the Server my code did not work andy more. I had Driver 17 installed on my Dev PC but the server had Driver 11 and 13 installed. So to just make everyting consitent I installed Driver 17 on the server and everthing worked.

Comment: @user3553260 I think using `'{SQL Server}'` might be an outdated approach; [this comment says that Driver is "ancient"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045834/pyodbc-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified#comment117095825_46055035)

Comment: Answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54206996/1175496) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39440803/1175496) suggest that `ODBC` clients are the successor to the native client , and how `SQL Server` and `SQL Server Native Client` are outdated/deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

**You could try**:

```
import pyodbc
# Using a DSN
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=odbc_datasource_name;UID=db_user_id;PWD=db_password')
```

**Note**: You will need to know the "odbc_datasource_name". In Windows you can search for ODBC Data Sources. The name will look something like this:

**[Data Source Name Example](https://www.google.se/search?q=odbc%20data%20source%20name&rlz=1C1GCEU_enSE824SE824&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiG1e7O-ZXfAhVHhSwKHWY1DekQ_AUIDigB&biw=1536&bih=758&safe=active&ssui=on#imgrc=tQi9KAPG37bVUM:)**

Comment: P.S I am not entirely sure which tab to look at for the Data Source Name.

Answer (score 3):

The below code works magic.

```
 SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "mssql+pyodbc://<servername>/<dbname>?driver=SQL Server Native Client 11.0?trusted_connection=yes?UID" \
                              "=<db_name>?PWD=<pass>"
```

Answer (score 2):

Below connection string is working

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc as odbc

sql_conn = odbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER=SERVER_NAME;DATABASE=DATABASE_NAME;UID=USERNAME;PWD=PASSWORD;')

query = "SELECT * FROM admin.TABLE_NAME"
df = pd.read_sql(query, sql_conn)
df.head()
```

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same error on python3 and this help me:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                      'SERVER=YourServerName;'
                      'DATABASE=YourDatabaseName;UID=USER_NAME;PWD=PASS_WORD;')
```

remember python is case-sensitive so you have to mention DRIVER,SERVER,... in upper case.
and you can visit this link for more information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was using wrong drivers to connect to Microsft SQL server

```
import pyodbc
print(pyodbc.drivers()) # this will list down all the drivers available in your local PC
```

I noticed that I was using "SQL server" as a driver for connecting to "Microsoft SQL server". I installed new ODBC driver and it worked well.

> Don't use "MySQL ODBC Unicode/ANSI driver" to connect to Microsoft SQL servers. Instead install latest (or older as per requirement) from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/release-notes-odbc-sql-server-windows?view=sql-server-ver16)

Also make sure that SQL server is allowed to accept remote connections.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the other answers, that considered the connection string itself, it might simply be necessary to download the correct odbc driver. My client just faced this issue when executing a python app, that required it.
you can check this by pressing windows + typing "odbc".
the correct driver should appear in the drivers tab.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed any product of SQL in your system machine ?
You can download and install "ODBC Driver 13(or any version) for SQL Server" and try to run if you havent alerady done.

Answer (score 1):

Create a DSN something like this (ASEDEV) for your connection and try to use DSN instead of DRIVER like below:

```
enter code here
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=ASEDEV;User ID=sa;Password=sybase123')
mycur = cnxn.cursor()
mycur.execute("select * from master..sysdatabases")
row = mycur.fetchone()
while row:
    print(row)
    row = mycur.fetchone()`
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue whole day wasted and I tried all possible `ODBC Driver` values

```
import pyodbc
connection = pyodbc.connect('Driver = {SQL Server};Server=ServerName;'
                            'Database=Database_Name;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
```

In place of `Driver = {SQL Server}` we can try these option one by one or just you can use with you corresponding setting, somehow in my case the last one works :)

```
Driver={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server} for SQL Server 2005 - 2014
Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server} for SQL Server 2005 - 2016
Driver={ODBC Driver 13.1 for SQL Server} for SQL Server 2008 - 2016
Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server} for SQL Server 2008 - 2017

Driver={SQL Server} for SQL Server 2000
Driver={SQL Native Client} for SQL Server 2005
Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0} for SQL Server 2008
Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0} for SQL Server 2012
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to download Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
from [Microsoft ODBC Driver 13](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50420)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have all drivers and db engine installed

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920

Comment: You might need the [MS Access 2013 runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39358) depending on your version of office as explained on this [Microsoft trouble shooting page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/cannot-use-odbc-or-oledb).

Comment: For me it was the db engine that was missing

Comment: Sorry for the down vote, I tried removing it but it's locked.

Comment: No worries, i don't care for the points :) And leaving the link here might help someone someday who knows

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the exact same error was caused by the lack of the drivers on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter running in an Azure virtual machine.

As soon as I installed the drivers from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56567, the issue was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
import pyodbc

server = 'servername'

database = 'DB'

username = 'UserName'

password = 'Password'

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)

cursor = cnxn.cursor()


cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Tbl')

for row in cursor:
    print('row = %r' % (row,))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
server = '123.45.678.90'
database = 'dbname'
username = 'username'
password = 'pwork'
driivver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
samgiongzon='DRIVER='+driivver+';SERVER='+server+\
                 ';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+\
                 ';PWD='+password+';Trusted_Connection=no;'
pyodbc.connect(samgiongzon, autocommit=True)
```

it worked for me; you need to install driver from here

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

or (in ubuntu) `sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev` if you get an error with `pip install pyodbc`

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me. What did work for me was the following:

Instead of passing a connection string like this:

```
conn_str = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=127.0.0.1;DATABASE=test;UID=root;PWD=root"
conn = pyodbc.connect(connstring=conn_str)
```

I passed the connection details as following:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(Driver="SQL Server",Server='127.0.0.1',Database='test',UID="root",PWD="root")
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

My issue; trying to connect using MFA and my email, which has the permissions for this database. I also made sure that I could connect to the database in the first place, just to be sure.

First of all, look at all the drivers:

```
import pyodbc   
print(pyodbc.drivers())
```

Now you can set up your connection string; I had the list of available drivers. For Azure Authentication (now Microsoft Entra Id) this code worked for me:

```
connstring = 'Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=<SERVER_NAME>;Database=<DB_NAME>;Uid=<me@myemailaddress>;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryInteractive'
```

This opened a small window asking me to connect and add the Authentication code.

Answer (score -1):

if any one are trying to access the database which is hosted in azure then try to give the driver as ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server

Answer (score -4):

if your system is 64 bit then make sure you have both python and sql 64 bit you will find both on the google
[how to download 64 bit python](https://youtu.be/3hzV1_FwWu0)