# Error in connecting Azure SQL database from Azure Machine Learning Service using python

Tags: python, sql, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to connect **Azure SQL Database** from **Azure Machine Learning service**, but I got the below error.

**Please check Error: -**

```
**('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')**
```

Please Check the below code that I have used for database connection: -

```
import pyodbc

class DbConnect:
    # This class is used for azure database connection using pyodbc
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.sql_db = pyodbc.connect(SERVER=<servername>;PORT=1433;DATABASE=<databasename>;UID=<username>;PWD=<password>')

            get_name_query = "select name from contacts"
            names = self.sql_db.execute(get_name_query)
            for name in names:
                print(name)

        except Exception as e:
            print("Error in azure sql server database connection : ", e)
            sys.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    class_obj = DbConnect()
```

Is there any way to solve the above error? Please let me know if there is any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd consider using [`azureml.dataprep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-dataprep/azureml.dataprep?view=azure-dataprep-py) over pyodbc for this task (the API may change, but this worked last time I tried):

```
import azureml.dataprep as dprep

ds = dprep.MSSQLDataSource(server_name=<server-name,port>,
                           database_name=<database-name>,
                           user_name=<username>,
                           password=<password>)
```

You should then be able to collect the result of an SQL query in pandas e.g. via

```
dataflow = dprep.read_sql(ds, "SELECT top 100 * FROM [dbo].[MYTABLE]")
dataflow.to_pandas_dataframe()
```

Comment: @Davide_Fiocco I tried above code before it's working fine, but want to access database using pyodbc. Is there any solution for it?

Comment: @AkshayGodase this and similar questions may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045834/pyodbc-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified in that case!

Comment: @Davide_Fiocco I tried the below syntax on Debian :-

`import pyodbc
print(pyodbc.drivers())`
I got the output is :- []
There is no any driver available that's why i got the above error.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can [create SQL datastore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.datastore(class)?view=azure-ml-py#register-azure-sql-database-workspace--datastore-name--server-name--database-name--tenant-id--client-id--client-secret--resource-url-none--authority-url-none--endpoint-none--overwrite-false-) and create a dataset from the SQL datastore.
Learn how: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-create-register-datasets#create-tabulardatasets

Sample code:

```
from azureml.core import Dataset, Datastore

# create tabular dataset from a SQL database in datastore
sql_datastore = Datastore.get(workspace, 'mssql')
sql_ds = Dataset.Tabular.from_sql_query((sql_datastore, 'SELECT * FROM my_table'))
```

@AkshayGodase Any particular reason that you want to use pyodbc?

Comment: @Sihui_Hu I have already connected the azure sql database using `azureml.datapreb` library but I am not able to store data into database using `azureml.datapreb` library. That's why I want to connect the database using pyodbc library.