# How to configure ODBC Name and Driver so it's recognized by pyodbc?

Tags: python, odbc, pyodbc

I'm trying to use Python to access our company's ERP data using a third party ODBC connection, but getting a strange error message.

I tried the spacing answer provided in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045834/pyodbc-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified) with no luck, and I don't see how the other answers would help me.

The OEM of the ODBC has a short tutorial posted [here](https://www.progress.com/tutorials/odbc/using-datadirect-odbc-drivers-with-python-and-pyodbc), they recommend using the pyodbc package to use the ODBC connector.  I've followed the ERP company's ODBC configuration documentation and was able to successfully test the connection from my PC:

[image]

Here's what the ODBC settings look like:
[image]

Following the tutorial (linked to above) I tried this simple script:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('DNS=PLEXODBC;UID=,<my_username>,PWD=<my_password>)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('''SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Part_v_Part''')
while True:
  row = cursor.fetchone()
  if not row:
    break
  print(row)
print('Done')
```

When I run this script I get the following error message:

```
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

The error doesn't make sense to me because when I look at the admin tools I can see there is a name and driver that does exist:

[image]

I'm not sure what to try next or how to get this to work.

Comment: You need to use `DSN=...`, not `DNS=...`.

Comment: palm to forehead and wiping egg off my face.  Thank you - this lead to another error message that makes more sense....