# Connection issues with Tally ODBC

Tags: python, pyodbc, tally

I am trying to connect tally ODBC to my Python and make a data frame but its showing me an error even while my tally is running as Admin.

```
import pyodbc

con="DSN=TallyODBC_9000;PORT=9000;DRIVER=Tally ODBC Driver;SERVER={(local)}"

conn=pyodbc.connect(con)
```

Getting this Error:

> InterfaceError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         4 con="PORT=9000;DRIVER=Tally ODBC Driver;SERVER=(local)"
>         5 
>   ----> 6 conn=pyodbc.connect(con)
>         7
>
> InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]
>   Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0)
>   (SQLDriverConnect)')

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PYODBC--Data source name not found and no default driver specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045834/pyodbc-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified)

Comment: If your ODBC DSN is defined correctly then it should already contain `DRIVER=`, etc. so it is not necessary to also include then in the connection string. That's sort of the whole point of creating a DSN.