# InterfaceError: Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)

Tags: python, ms-access

This question has been asked before (see link below) but I'm still having issues even though both my Python and MS Office are 64-bit. After ensuring both are 64-bit, I tried running the following code:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=Q:\Data Requests\Boarding.accdb;')
```

but still got the following error:

```
InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Also of note, I am able to connect and pull data into Python from my SQL server just fine using this code:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=ENTSNR;'
                      'Database=EMData;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[PYODBC--Data source name not found and no default driver specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045834/pyodbc-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified/46055035#46055035)

Comment: I see you're working using jupyter, you're running that locally, right? Can you just output pyodbc.drivers(), without that filter?

Comment: Correct, I am running in Jupyter and locally! What do you mean by output pyodbc.drivers(), without that filter? Thanks!!

Comment: @Raven - just `print(pyodbc.drivers())`

Comment: That returns: ['SQL Server']

Comment: That's truly odd. You're 100% sure you're running this locally, connecting to Jupyter using localhost as the address? Only having that driver sounds an awful lot like a managed installation, there are nearly always more drivers present by default.

Comment: @ErikA Is there an easy was to determine if I'm running Juptyer locally(my IT dept installed it for me)?

Comment: You can do `import socket` then `socket.gethostname()`, and compare that to your PC hostname, for example.

Comment: Hmm the output from the code you detailed above matches my device name.

Comment: Well, I'm at a loss then. You can double-check architecture as well if you haven't set it up yourself, `import platform` then `platform.architecture()`,

Comment: thanks for trying! It still says 64-bit!