# Connect pyodbc to SQL Server

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to SQL Server using Python's pyodbc. What I have is

```
conn= pyodbc.connect('Driver ={SQL server Native Client 19.0};'
                          'Server = ('my server name;'
                          'Database ='my database name;'
                          'Trusted_Connection = yes;')
```

But I get:

> pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002, '[IM002][Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified(0)(SQLDriverConnect).

Not sure how to correct it?

Comment: FWIW I've never seen mention of an ODBC driver named `SQL server Native Client 19.0`. `SQL Server Native Client 11.0` is the newest one that *I've* seen .... Also, those round brackets do not belong in a connection string.

Comment: To add: the [Native Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-ver15) is deprecated per MSDN docs. 11.0 unsupported after SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the space after "Driver"; make it "Driver=" as spaces can sometimes be the cause of issues when handling SQL as pointed out by the top answer in [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045834/pyodbc-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified) with the same error message as you. If this does not work, try looking at the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045834/pyodbc-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified) to solve your issue.

Initial Answer (redundant as points out typo that exists only on StackOverflow): You have a typo. Do Ctrl + F and find "Databasde" to find your typo. Change this to Database.

Your program is finding a database called "Databasde" instead of "Database", as this is what you have technically told it to do.

Disclaimer:

I work entirely with SQLite3 as I find it much easier to use so I'm not 100% certain on what's causing the problem, but I do know that the syntax looks weird in comparisons to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045834/pyodbc-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified).

Comment: sorry that is my type. thanks for point that out. I made that type during the asking of the question. what I have in the actual script is Databse = .....'

Comment: @PChao I've edited my answer with a possible solution for you. I hope it helps.