# How to connect to Azure sql database through python anaconda jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to connect to azure sql database through Jupyter notebook and later to load the data into excel/csv .I  have the details of server and database only  .Username & password i think by default its taking my desktop credentials(unsure).

Here is tried code

```py
import pyodbc 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(Server=myserver;Database=mydatabase)
```

Comment: `cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=' + driver + ';SERVER=' +
    server + ';PORT=1433;DATABASE=' + database +
    ';UID=' + username + ';PWD=' + password)`
You can give Username and Password in this format

Comment: Have you found a solution? does my answer is acceptable or you need more help?

Answer (score 2):

In order to connect to your Azure SQL database with your jupyter notebook use the following:

```
import pyodbc

server = 'tcp:SQLSERVER.database.windows.net' # Server example
database = '<INSERT DATABASE NAME>' 
username = '<INSERT USERNAME>' 
password = '<INSER PASSWORD>' 
driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}' # Driver example
connection= pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=' + driver + ';SERVER=' +server + ';PORT=1433;DATABASE=' + database +';UID=' + username + ';PWD=' + password)

cursor = connection.cursor() # Just something you can do
print(connection)
connection.close()
```

For more details you can refer to the following links:

1. [Connect to Azure SQL Database using Python and Jupyter Notebook](https://sfoteini.github.io/blog/connect-to-azure-sql-database-using-python-and-jupyter-notebook/)
2. [Connect to Azure SQL Database in a Jupyter Notebook using Python](https://luke.geek.nz/azure/connect-to-azure-sql-database-in-a-jupyter-notebook-using-python/)
3. [Quickstart: Use Python to query a database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-python?view=azuresql)

Comment: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)') i am getting this error, so the ODBC installation to be done? will the driver installation be independent based on the  projects?

Comment: you've run the code I specified? you've created the database according to the guides or did you do some custom configurations? (either way I reccomend checking the third link I supplied to you, it explains everything)

Comment: @Trend try this following answer to your error: [Data source name not found and no default driver specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045834/pyodbc-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified)

Answer (score 0):

You need to give username, password of the Azure SQL database in connextion. Below is the code to establish connection of Azure SQl database using python in Jupyter Notebook.

```py
import pyodbc
# Establish the connection
server =  'xxxxx.database.windows.net'
database =  'xxx'
username =  'xxxx'
password =  'xxxx'
driver=  '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='  + driver +  ';SERVER='  +
server +  ';PORT=1433;DATABASE='  + database +
';UID='  + username +  ';PWD='  + password)
print(conn)
conn.close()
```

[image]

Reference: [Use Python to query a database - Azure SQL Database & SQL Managed Instance | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-python?view=azuresql)